# JWT with invalid format

Tags: actframework

when checking the token on https://jwt.io/ I get Warning: Looks like your JWT signature is not encoded correctly using base64url (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5). Note that padding ("=") must be omitted as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-2

"~" Or "=" should be omitted

```java
@GetAction("login")
@ResponseContentType(H.MediaType.JSON)
public Result login(User user,ActionContext context){
     context.login("admin");
     return jwt();
}
```

return

```json
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJpc3N1ZXIiLCJleHAiOjE1NjgzOTAyMjMsImp0aSI6IjY5MDNhZjAwLWE1NGUtNGVkYi1iMjc2LWEwNWZmN2IzZTQ3MyIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4ifQ~~.SFzY3N974wQaP-_x_YxMr4-Nk1k5-TfOl-So_ZB424vl1p5yQ5-wfQhErDmdoVOFL2iRp0G2U_-Igi9Pu6GEWg~~"
}
```

Comment: ...and why is this causing a problem for you?

Comment: @Anderson can you please raise an issue to https://github.com/actframework/actframework/issues? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I pasted the token with "" when i omitted them the error went away.